# Imagine, get mime type

Tags: php, php-imagine

I cant find in imagine documentation https://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html how can i get mime type.

I just open an image like this:

```
$myImage = $imagine->open('/path/to/image.gif');
```

I have now $myImage, how can i get mime type?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're sure you're always working with images, you can use `exif_imagetype` like described in [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) by passing the same path you opened.  Mixed with `image_type_to_mime_type` (documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php)) you should be able to achieve your desired results.

```
$filename = '/path/to/image.gif';
$myImage = $imagine->open($filename);
$imagetype = exif_imagetype($filename);
if($imagetype) // check that you have a valid type, but most likely always the case
    $mimetype = image_type_to_mime_type($imagetype);
```